# How change language Resources in api .net Core with appsettings?

Tags: c#, .net-core, resources

I need to know how i can change language in my api .net core when start or deploy the same, defining in appsettings.json the language wanted.
I saw about Localization and Globalization, but i dont need such a solution complicated.

For example... i have two resources files, Language (english) and Language.es (spanish):

[image]

[image]

After in my **appsettings.json** i define the language wanted:

[image]

And i stablish the language change in my **Startup.cs**:

[image]

I just need in the code the resource reference according to the configuration.

[image]

But actually only obtain the responses in Spanish (server have language spanish default).
**How i can change the language resource ?**

Comment: "I saw about Localization and Globalization," - that is waht .NET gives you. Whether you find them complicated or not. The alternative is writing it all yourself. THAT SAID: An API should walys be language independent, leaving any sort of language specifics (including error texts) to the UI. You are inviting problems long tterm by going langauge specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Thread.CurrentThread` you are only setting the culture for the current thread at startup. Try using these properties to set the culture for all threads in the application:

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(appSettings.Language)
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

For more information have a look at the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=netcore-3.1